# splitting a file.txt into two file with a condition

Tags: linux, shell

How can i split the given file into two different files results codes and warning codes.AS given below is single text file and I want to split it into two files as  I had lot more file in such condition to split.

**Result Codes:**

```
0 - SYS_OK - "Ok"

1 - SYS_ERROR_E - "System Error"

1001 - MVE_SYS_E - "MTE System Error"

1002 - MVE_COMMAND_SYNTAX_ERROR_E - "Command Syntax is wrong"
```

**Warning Codes:**

```
0 - SYS_WARN_W - "System Warning"

100001 - MVE_SYS_W - "MVE System Warning"

200001 - SLEA_SYS_W - "SLEA System Warning"

200002 - SLEA_INCOMPLETE_SCRIPTED_OVERRIDE_COMMAND_W - "One or more of the entered scripted override commands has missing mandatory parameters"

300001 - L1_SYS_W - "L1 System Warning"
```

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried so far?

Comment: @jonk i tried grepline number of warning codes: and sed text file1 from line number to end and  text file2 to frist to line number

Comment: Show us **what exactly** you have tried and what **exact problems** you heve faced with these attempts. Add this information via editing your question post.

Answer (score 1):

Well, on first glance, the distinction seems to be that "warnings" all contain the character sequence `_W -` and anything that doesn't is "results". Did you notice that?

```
awk '/_W -/{print >"warnings";next}{print >"results"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python solution:
 I am assuming you are having the list of warning codes.

```
import re
warnings = open(r'warning-codes.txt');
warn_codes =[]
for line in warnings:
    m = re.search(r'(\d+) .*',line);
    if(m):
        warn_codes.append(m.groups(1));

ow = open('output-warnings.txt','w')
ors = open('output-results.txt','w')

log_file = open(r'log.txt');
for line in log_file:
    m = re.search(r'(\d+) .*',line);
    if(m and (m.groups(1) in warn_codes)):
        ow.write(line+'\n');
    elif(m):
        ors.write(line+'\n');
    else:
        print("none");

ow.close()
ors.close()
```

Comment: I have stored all the warning codes in an array and had simply matched if the current line has a warning code or result codes, and had written it to two different files!